# How to find a specific data in csv file

Tags: r, csv, import

I have a lots of csv files, I want to find some data in this.because in each files the data position is different, so I want to know how to find the data in red box in different csv files.

In csv file, it include the same data like the different month, I have an idea is that find the `EnergyconsumptionElectricallyNaturalgasmonthly` in csv file and then feedback the position, according the position choose the red box data.

[image]

Comment: Is it at least on the same row in each csv or could it be anywhere?

Comment: Please provide example CSV.

Comment: Are the months always on column B? and next column is always "ELECTRICITY"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the file line by line using *readLines*:

```
con <- file("temp2Table.csv", "r")
x <- readLines(con)
close(con)
```

Then find the row where we need to subset:

```
grep("EnergyConsumptionElectricityNaturalGasMonthly", x)
# [1] 16534
```

Once we know the row number, we can subset following 16 rows as below, and
write it out to a file:

```
write(x[ grep("EnergyConsumptionElectricityNaturalGasMonthly", x) + 4:20 ], "tempOut.csv")
```

Then we can read the file as normal csv:

```
dfClean <- read.csv("tempOut.csv")
```

And subset columns as we need:

```
dfClean[, 2:3]
#                      X.1 ELECTRICITY.FACILITY..kWh.
# 1                January                   11675.57
# 2               February                    9148.04
# 3                  March                   13862.50
# 4                  April                   16274.57
# 5                    May                   23918.16
# 6                   June                   29293.78
# 7                   July                   32953.04
# 8                 August                   34111.54
# 9              September                   24398.53
# 10               October                   14577.93
# 11              November                   13931.94
# 12              December                   12137.73
# 13                                               NA
# 14 Annual Sum or Average                  236283.34
# 15     Minimum of Months                    9148.04
# 16     Maximum of Months                   34111.54
```

Answer (score 0):

I would read the csv's and subset the terms you want to. Assuming they all have the same file structure and are contained in the same folder, you could do the following:

```
library(data.table) # library needed for fread, you can just use read.csv if you prefer

# create a list of the files in the folder
folder <- 'address_to_folder' # skip the last "/"
files <- list.files(path = folder, pattern="*.csv")

# read the files into a list and then transform it into a data.frame
mycsv <- lapply(paste(folder, pattern, sep = '/'), fread)
mydata <- rbindlist(mycsv)

# This part will need interpretation of the data frame, 
# you have to see where the column you want is, 
# if it is correctly formatted and how you can search it
search_result <- mydata[ mydata$column = 'search term', ]
```

Comment: Firstly ,Thank you answer my  question ,I have edit my question can you help to reslove the question .secondly I don't konw how to upload the csv file ,can you tell me ? thank you